# error: array required, but String found

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to make transfer my code with a code that has methods instead

I was transferring all the stuff but i am getting errors all over

edit 4:

My Original Code:

```css
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Testing1
{
   public static void main(String[] myFile)
   {
       //This array will serve as the storage for the integers.
      Integer [] listOfIntegers = new Integer[10000];
      Integer index = new Integer(0); 
      int count = 0;
          
      if(myFile.length == 0)
      {
            //This prompt will show when no input detected on the command line arguments.
         System.out.println("Please input the file name.");
      }
      else
      {
            //Otherwise, it will read the text file.
         File data = new File(myFile[0]);
         Scanner inputData = null;
         try 
         {
             //This will create a connection to the file.
            inputData = new Scanner(data);
         } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
         {
              //This message will appear when the text file entered doesn't exist.
            System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for: \"");
            System.out.println(myFile[0]+ "\"");
         } 
            //If the text file does exist, it will go through the file.
         if (inputData != null)
         {
            System.out.print("number of integers in file " + " \"");
            System.out.println(myFile[0] + "\"");
         
            while (inputData.hasNextLine())
            {
               try
               {  
                   //reads an integer in a line of text       
                  Integer element = inputData.nextInt();
                  listOfIntegers[count] = element;
                 //prints out the integer and and its index in the array
                  System.out.println("index = " + index + ", element = " + element);
                  index ++;
                  count ++;
               }
               catch (InputMismatchException e)
               {
                  String word = inputData.next();
               }
               catch (NoSuchElementException e)
               {
                   //to avoid program crashing against this exception.
               }
            }//end of while
            System.out.print("\nTotal number of integers in file: " + " \"");
            System.out.println(myFile[0] + "\"" + " = " + count);
         }//end of if 
      }//end of else       
   }//end of main
}//end of class
```

working code now but null values showing for the element and doesn't stop at the input file's intended index.

```css
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Testing1
   public static void main(String[] args)throws InputMismatchException
   {
      if(args.length == 0)
      {
            //This prompt will show when no input detected on the command line arguments.
         System.out.println("Please input the file name.");
      }
      else
      {
         Integer[] array = Testing1.readFileReturnIntegers(args[0]);
         Testing1.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, args[0]);
      }
   }// end of main
     
   public static Integer []readFileReturnIntegers(String inputData)
   { 
      Integer [] listOfIntegers = new Integer[10000];
      Integer index = new Integer(0); 
      int count = 0;
      
      File data = new File(inputData);
      Scanner inputReader = null;
      try 
      {
             //This will create a connection to the file.
         inputReader = new Scanner(data);
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
      {
              //This message will appear when the text file entered doesn't exist.
         System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for: \"");
         System.out.println(inputData+ "\"");
      } 
            //If the text file does exist, it will go through the file.
      if (inputData != null)
      {
         System.out.print("number of integers in file " + " \"");
         System.out.println(inputData + "\"");
                  while (inputReader.hasNextLine())
         {
            try
            {  
                   //reads an integer in a line of text       
               Integer element = inputReader.nextInt();
               listOfIntegers[count]=element;
                 //prints out the integer and and its index in the array
               System.out.println("index = " + index + ", element = " + element);
               index ++;
               count ++;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
               String word = inputReader.next();
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                   //to avoid program crashing against this exception.
            }
         }//end of while
      }
                
      return listOfIntegers;             
   }//end of readFileReturnIntegers
        
   public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(Integer [] array, String inputData)
   {  
      int count = 0; 
      System.out.print("\nTotal number of integers in file: " + " \"");
      System.out.println(inputData + "\"" + " = " + count);
      
   }//end of printArrayAndIntegerCount
         
}//end of class
```

my error:

```css
Testing1.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
      return array;             
             ^
  symbol:   variable array
  location: class Testing1
1 error
```

I wanted to output the integers from the input files electricity.txt and 1000txt.

```css
number of integers in file "electricity.txt" = 4
    index = 0, element = 1877
    index = 1, element = 1923
    index = 2, element = 1879
    index = 3, element = 2000
```

and this one

```css
number of integers in file "1000.txt" = 1001
    index = 0, element = 1000
    index = 1, element = 2
    index = 2, element = 3
    index = 3, element = 5
    index = 4, element = 7
    index = 5, element = 11
    index = 6, element = 13
    index = 7, element = 17
    index = 8, element = 19
    index = 9, element = 23
    to index 1000 and element 7919
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: This headline would fit to 99% of the posts here. Can you come up with a more descriptive title?

Comment: `public static Integer []readFileReturnIntegers(String inputData)` is cause for error  `File data = new File(inputData[0]);` (first errror)

Comment: sorry folks renamed the title

Comment: oh shoot fixed @asteriskninja ! i noticed i am trying to use an array on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the updated Answer**

It is better to use ArrayList in this case, so we can create dynamic array.
where it's is not possible with array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Testing1 {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws InputMismatchException
   {
      if(args.length == 0)
      {
            //This prompt will show when no input detected on the command line arguments.
         System.out.println("Please input the file name.");
      }
      else
      {
         ArrayList<Integer> array = Testing1.readFileReturnIntegers(args[0]);
         Testing1.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, args[0]);
      }
   }// end of main

   public static ArrayList<Integer> readFileReturnIntegers(String inputData)
   { 
      ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
      int count = 0;

      File data = new File(inputData);
      Scanner inputReader = null;
      try 
      {
               //This will create a connection to the file.
         inputReader = new Scanner(data);
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
      {
                   //This message will appear when the text file entered doesn't exist.
         System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for: \"");
         System.out.println(inputData+ "\"");
      } 
            //If the text file does exist, it will go through the file.
      if (inputData != null)
      {
         System.out.print("number of integers in file " + " \"");
         System.out.println(inputData + "\"");
                  while (inputReader.hasNextLine())
         {
            try
            {  
                   //reads an integer in a line of text       
               Integer element = inputReader.nextInt();
               listOfIntegers.add(element);
                    //prints out the integer and and its index in the array
               System.out.println("index = " + count + ", element = " + element);
               count ++;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
               String word = inputReader.next();
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                      //to avoid program crashing against this exception.
            }
         }//end of while
      }

      return listOfIntegers;             
   }//end of readFileReturnIntegers

   public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(ArrayList<Integer> array, String filename)
   {  
      System.out.print("\nTotal number of integers in file: " + " \"");
      System.out.println(filename + "\"" + " = " + array.size());

   }//end of printArrayAndIntegerCount

}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing1.java:40, remove [0]

```
File data = new File(inputData);
```

inputData itself your file name, so use **inputData** instead of **inputData[0]** everywhere in System.out.println

Comment: you must explain, why you did that to provide clarity

Comment: Lemme add the original code that i was trying to convert that needed methods instead of what i had. i had to reorganize the format since there is readfilereturnintegers and then printarrayreturnintegers stuff

Comment: only have one error Testing1.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
      return array;          
             ^
  symbol:   variable array
  location: class Testing
1 error
but it requires me to have a return statement

Comment: You declared public static Integer []readFileReturnIntegers(String inputData) as int[], so you must return array @aldz24

Comment: this is the error it shows when i do the return array statement,  did i also have to add in an array inside my loop?

Comment: error is Testing1.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
      return array;             
             ^
  symbol:   variable array
  location: class Testing1
1 error
@SureshGogu

Comment: It means that you didn't created any array with name array, return listOfIntegers @aldz24

Comment: ;_; thanks i got it working now ! but the issue is now that my output file is showing nulls now i will add the input files i want to do

Comment: you are not pushing integer into array, you are just printing it, you need to add element to array after **Integer element = inputReader.nextInt();** @aldz24

Comment: How do i go about doing that again? i mean adding the element to the array?

Comment: listOfIntegers[count] = element before count ++; which error you are getting? @aldz24

Comment: no errors now, i managed to fix it but it is still showing null since i'm going over the index limit of my input files which are listed above : 1000.txt which has 1000 index and electricity which only has 4. i think the issue is my integer array is list at 10000... but is there a way to fix my loop to stop at a certain index based from the input files?

Comment: we can also do with array, but while finding number of integers we need to iterate over array until we found null to get actual length. it is easy with ArrayList, check updated answer @aldz24